# how to accomplish concurrency when using asyncio.create_task

Tags: python-asyncio

It can accomplish concurrency with asyncio in the form below :

```
async def say_after(delay, what):
    print(f'{what} {delay}')
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(f'over {what} {delay}')


async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, "hello"))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, "world"))
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    await task1
    await task2
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

```
started at 10:18:54
hello 1
world 2
over hello 1
over world 2
finished at 10:18:56
```

But when I change the form of function 'main' into :

```
async def main():
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, "hello"))
    await task1
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, "world"))
    await task2
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")
```

It perfoms kind of sequential execution.

```
started at 10:18:33
hello 1
over hello 1
world 2
over world 2
finished at 10:18:36
```

So why dose the latter not perform in concurrency?

Comment: `await` is a blocking operation. `main` will wait for `task1` to finish before moving on to create `task2`.

Comment: [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) is probably what you’re looking for.

Comment: @dirn but why is the former runs in concurrency? Is there any differences between these two forms?

Comment: In the first version you schedule both tasks and then say “wait for the first one to finish.” The second one is allowed to run while the first one is waiting for the sleep.